# Proof: Linear Regression

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, proof

I am at a loss how might one prove $\text{Var}{(\hat{y}_h)} = \sigma^2 \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_h-\bar{x})^2}{S_{xx}}\right)$.  Note that $\hat{y}_h$ = $b_0 + b_1X_h$ which is a regression line estimate at some given $X_h$.

Moreover, what is the second term actually saying?  I understand the first is just the variance divided by the degrees of freedom but the second is more complex it seems.

Comment: please add the self-study tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an outline:

- Write down the formula for  $\hat{y}_h$.
- Take the variance of it.

The second involves rather similar steps to your earlier variance question.

The second term is related to the effect of the uncertainty in the slope estimate on the uncertainty in the fitted value; this gets bigger the further you get from the mean $x$.

> I am quite rusty on how to take the variance of multiple terms like this

Just keep using basic properties of things you know about, like:

$\text{Var}(X+Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) + 2\, \text{Cov}(X,Y)$

$\text{Var}(aX) = a^2\text{Var}(X)$

$ \text{Cov}(aX,bY)= ab\,\text{Cov}(X,Y)$

and so on

Take advantage of independence when you can.

Note that when *using* those formulas, your $x$'s in the regression takes the role of constants, not random variables. Only functions of $y$'s are random variables (the estimates of the parameters are functions of the $y$'s, however).

Comment: Much appreciated.  I know that $\hat{y}_h$ = $b_0 + b_1 \hat{x_h}$ but I am quite rusty on how to take the variance of multiple terms like this.  If I can do this then I believe after that I am meant to substitute $b_0 = Y - b_1X$ or something similar.  If I recall manipulating variance I will have $Var(b_0) + Var(b_1) + 2Cov(b1,b0)$ does that seem right?

Comment: see the edit to my answer. Don't put hats on $x$; the $x$'s are known. edit: ah, your edit to your comment is not quite right, there should be an $x$ in there

Comment: Right, so it should be something like $Var(b_0) + XVar(b_1) + 2Cov(Xb_1,b_0)$?  What's strange about all of this is that in my notes somehow I have Cov(b_0,b_1) being the only remaining term that then yields the result through a series of manipulations.

Comment: *Like* that, but not that; you have an error.

Comment: Is there any possible way that we could be left with the term $Cov(b_0,b_1)$ alone?  In my notes it seems to go that we then have $\sum cov(Y_i / n,k_i Y_i)$ - $\frac{x(\sigma^2)}{S_{xx}}$ by expanding this, which quickly leads to the desired result.

Comment: Yes, and I agree that there should be $x$s there but it seems that covariance term does the job itself which confuses me.

Comment: (redone, because I was expanding on my points) What are you computing the variance *of*? Does it have an $x$ in it? If so, you can't wish that away.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you explain how the $x$ "goes away"? Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry Glen, I thought that you asked that question initially as a hint to help me move in the right direction.  I meant initially to use your notation but didn't know how to add the hat.  Let $\hat{y}_h$ = $b_0 + b_1X_h$ which is a regression line estimate at some given $X_h$.

Comment: I also cannot explain how the $X_h$ vanishes but it does happen that $cov(b_0,b_1)$ alone yields $\sigma^2(1/n) +\frac{(X_h- X)^2}{S_{xx}}$.

Comment: "*didn't know how to add the hat*" -- you can always ask, or you can google things like *mathematical symbols in LaTeX* and find many pages like [this](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html) (under 'math mode accents') or [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)

Comment: Again, all I can say is *carefully check what you're computing*. A third alternative for finding out how to do stuff in LaTeX is to right click on some mathematics you want to emulate here, `Show Math As`, then select `TeX Commands`, and copy/paste the LaTeX code from the window.

Comment: Thanks Glen, I have started another question to address the issue with covariance.